# Having some trouble debugging this function

Tags: r, for-loop, debugging

I am trying to create a function that starts at a given point, [j,i], and for the entire dataset (i.e., every row "j" and every column "i") takes the average of the past two datapoints and subtracts it from the average of the past six datapoints.

These recalculated datapoints (with each point being the average of the past two points minus the average of the past six points) would then create their own new dataframe.

```r
for (i in 1:ncol(data)){
   function_1 <- function(x){
     for(j in 1:nrow(data)){
       if (j > 6) {
       x[j,i] <- sapply(x[(j-2):j,i], mean, na.rm = TRUE)-sapply(x[(j-6):j,i], mean, na.rm = TRUE)
       }
     }
   }
}
```

However, it doesn't work. How can I deebug this?

Comment: Your code defines a function (multiple times) but never calls it.

Comment: Also, "data" does not exist in the function enviroment, maybe you meant "x"? You say that it creates its own dataframe but you are overwriting the one given to the function. Also, your function never returns a value.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues ere:

1. You define your funtion repetitively inside a loop
2. you never execute it.

Try this:

```
function_1 <- function(x){
  for (i in 1:ncol(data)){
    for(j in 1:nrow(data)){
      if (j > 6) {
        x[j,i] <- sapply(x[(j-2):j,i], mean, na.rm = TRUE)-sapply(x[(j-6):j,i], mean, na.rm = TRUE)
      }
    }
  }
}

function_1(x)
```

Comment: Yeah sorry forgot to add the execution. I was running it and it returned “null” repeatedly. I will try this though thank you!